# Recommended best practice for add/remove from a list during onboarding

Tags: lists, checkboxes, onboarding

Trying to understand what the best practices are for setup/onboarding use case like this. We're asking the user to customize their feed of newsletters in this instance; user can remove item from those we automatically added or add a new one from a list we originally filtered out.

Here are two original options. With the first one, there's a hover effect where a checkbox appears (like Gmail bulk actions).

Any help is appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Two lists**

It is clear to me which newsletters I have subscribed to and which not. Hover effect is a bit hidden IMO. I think it is uncommon for a checkbox to "move" things around. Usually, you activate or deactivate a setting. Why not show the checkboxes all the time and make it a plain and simple list with checkboxes?

**List with buttons**

It is not clear to me which newsletters I have subscribed to. Ofc, you can deduct it from the greyscale images, but that is too subtle IMO. Also the list seems to be arbitrarily ordered and not alphabetically (if somebody does not get that it is actually two lists). You might go around this by using a toggle switch which communicates both state and action. But then again, why not use an alphabetically sorted list with checkboxes?

Comment: I would use the list with buttons, but with different coloured (in colours that a colourblind could see) Add and Remove buttons.

Comment: Thanks both! I'm leaning towards the list with buttons because of scrolling UX. It's unlikely that the first list will be just 6 items like on the screenshot here so user will be scrolling up and down and we want them to easily toggle on/off the newsletters.

Comment: Any feedback on the 'Go to your feed' CTA button? Wasn't sure what the best practice is regarding placing main CTA button at the top like here but it kind of makes sense to me since the list below that will be scrollable?

Comment: @mishan would love to hear your take.

Comment: Is your top bar with CTA fixed or will it disappear when scrolling down?

Comment: @Nash yep - it's fixed so everything below is scrollable

Comment: Or is it better to have the CTA button fixed at the bottom of the screen and have the scrollable list above like here? https://screenlane.com/media/screenshots/over-ios-app-screenshot-thumbnail-2bf5.jpg

Comment: @JurajPal Well, I'd prefer the go-to feed on top and maybe floating when scrolling - it the list is loooong. If it's not I don't care. The button at the bottom only if it's consistent with the rest of the app - if you do it once you should keep consistent and that's possibly robbing you of screen real estate in other areas where it might be important. Now that I think about it I would only float it on a list that's larger than some size and leave it scrolling otherwise, whether the final is top or bottom or both - and keep consistent with the rest of app.